# Socket.io can't find localhost

Tags: node.js, socket.io, localhost, http-status-code-404

I was following [this basic tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxzOqP9YwmM), when I quickly found out that socket.io doesn't seem to detect my index.html and localhost gives error message 404. So maybe I had mistyped something, thus I copied [the files](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Realtime-Simple-Chat-App) from the tutorial, but the same issue persists. What am I missing?

Comment: FYI, that tutorial provides NO way to actually load `index.html` since the simple server in that example is only a socket.io server and there is no regular http server that can serve index.html.  So, how are you loading index.html?

Comment: I thought socket.io would load it similar to express.

Comment: No.  socket.io ONLY responds to socket.io requests, not regular web page requests.  Go to the socket.io web site for examples of how to use socket.io WITH Express like [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat).

Comment: I see, thanks. Strange how the tutorial is missing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io by itself ONLY responds to socket.io requests, not regular web page requests. So, if you want your server to both work with socket.io and be a regular web server to serve web pages, then you will need to integrate a regular web server together with your socket.io code.

The socket.io web site has an example of how to use socket.io WITH Express like [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat).  The basic concept (from the socket.io doc) is this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```